# Name of Emacs Lisp library that provides `with-gensyms' classic macro

Tags: elisp, elisp-macros

I have the feeling that Emacs Lisp macros are written in some different way than Common Lisp macros. This can't be true, but where is all the `gensym` things? Recently I was writing a macro and I needed to avoid capturing a lexical variable, so I started searching for `gensym` function. There is no such function! How can a Lisp that has macros don't have `gensym`? Maybe it's handled differently in Emacs Lisp?

I've found `gensym` in `cl-lib`, that's already something. But what I really need is `with-gensyms`. Do you know where can I find such a macro (third party package is fine if it's in ELPA or MELPA, although it should be built in Emacs by now, I think).

I'm ready to write these eight lines myself, but this sort of thing shouldn't be rewritten every time, IMHO.

---

**Edit**: to make it clear: I'm searching for a way to get this once and for all, that's a library that contains it that I can depend upon. If you think it's OK to rewrite it everywhere every time developer needs it -- that's your point of view. If you vote to close the question simply because there is no such library and

> Lisp hackers generally do what is practical for them, such as writing a small utility macro and leaving it at that

-- I think *your* reasoning is fallacious. Lisp hackers generally don't like to redo something simply because *that's how people do it*. They create what they need and then use it everywhere.

There are quite a few different libraries that make life easier, and they often do *more trivial* things. Yet when I ask for something that's useful but missing I get this typical answer "well, don't you know, just copy paste it from Goggle because it isn't there".

You can of course close this question, but IMHO it's normal question asking for certain tool that Emacs Lisp developer might find useful in some cases. If you don't know decent solution, that doesn't mean that the question is bad.

Comment: Here's the [EmacsWiki page on macro utilities](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MacroUtilities) that includes `with-gensyms`.  It was the first hit from a [Google search for "emacs with-gensyms"](https://www.google.com/search?q=emacs+with-gensyms&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Comment: @Dan, I don't use Google, but I've seen this already, although I missed that this is a package (or rather a elisp file). How can I depend on this thing? It's not in ELPA/MELPA, it seems.

Comment: It's also the first hit in a DuckDuckGo search and the second in a Yahoo search; the point is that it's easy-access.  There's a lot of older code out there that's not in (M)ELPA.  I've not used it and so can't vouch for it, but it's 4 lines of code and could easily be tucked into your init file somewhere.

Comment: @Dan, The problem here is not that it's easy to write / find on the net, but that I'm writing stuff that other people will use and I need a piece of reusable (classic) code to avoid reinventing the wheel. I can't put it into my init file because I'm not planning to ship it with the package I'm writing. I hope I made myself clear now.

Comment: @Dan, Oh I see that there is `org-with-gensyms`. This means that every package should redefine the same thing...

Comment: Welcome to Emacs Lisp coding!

Comment: @wasamasa, I think I will just write a library and put it on MELPA for a start. This should include all the missing stuff and maybe a bit more. It could be called `m` (for macros). If there is already something like this, I will use that instead.

Comment: Please don't put it on MELPA unless there is overwhelming interest in yet another single-letter library.

Comment: @wasamasa, given limited number of letters we can use, I won't. There are unfair things in naming ELisp packages though, for example you are advised to use prefixes everywhere and this is OK, because we need to emulate namespaces, but special packages don't give a f***, they can use two-letter prefixes whenever they want and use `/` Clojure styled delimiters (not advised), although their names are not two-letter symbols. What the f*** multiple cursors prefixes everything with `mc/` ? Is it unique package with such a right? Get it prefix everything with `multiple-cursors-`.

Comment: Well, iirc `with-gensyms` is from Alexandria, it isn't standard CL either. Disclaimer: I didn't use this library, but I'm convinced that hygienic macros are better for many purposes than CL-style ones, and here's a library that claims to implement them in ELisp: https://github.com/ijp/mbe.el . Perhaps, if you are looking for a library to do a lot of macrology, this can come in handy.

Comment: @wvxvw, yes, but CL has its Alexandria, which is kinda standard library to use in most cases.

Comment: Anyhow, see if `mbe-bind` from the library I mentioned won't do the same thing. It's not exactly `with-gensysms` it's more like `destructuring-bind`, but it's a macro, meaning that all symbols used in it are fresh ones.

Comment: @wvxvw, why oh why they don't write doc-strings! This can be used, but we need to generate list of gensymed symbols before pattern matching it, and that's cumbersome, equal to rewriting of `with-gensyms`. Thanks for the link, though.

Comment: I'm voting for a close as I have no clue what the actual question is. That aside, the reasoning is fallacious. Emacs Lisp is different from Common Lisp, best practices are more of a joke and Lisp hackers generally do what is practical for them, such as writing a small utility macro and leaving it at that.

Comment: Mark: `M-x report-emacs-bug` and suggest that `org-with-gensyms` be extracted and renamed to `with-gensyms` (or maybe `cl-with-gensyms`, depending on where it is most sensibly relocated to) for more general use.

Comment: I agree with @wasamasa. There is much that is fallacious, misleading, or unclear in the question. You say you are "*searching for gensym function. There is no such function!*". The function is there; it is `make-symbol`. But then you go on to ask about `with-gensyms` - which is anyway not part of Common Lisp, and which people have anyway shown the (trivial) code for. You complain that you want a  "*collection of standard abstractions given without need to reimplement them again and again.*" But which such abstractions? Nothing clear specified by this question in that regard. Voting to close.

Comment: @phils: subr-x.el would be a good place for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [Missing Macro Tools](https://github.com/mrkkrp/mmt). It's available on MELPA.

The package provides the following classics:

- `mmt-gensym`
- `mmt-make-gensym-list`
- `mmt-with-gensyms`
- `mmt-with-unique-names`
- `mmt-once-only`

Comment: Upvoted for providing the code for others, but (as before) please consider contributing them to Emacs if you feel that these are useful missing features from the standard libraries.

Comment: @phils, If it proves useful for people, I will consider proposing it to FSF. The only thing that scares me is all this paper work. Too bad FSF cannot add something without having developers sign papers.

Comment: The copyright assignment is an added hurdle for sure, but it's really a very small amount of paperwork, and there's a reason for it. It does prove to be a sticking point for a few people; but I think most find it's something they're happy to do in order to be able to give something back to the FSF and GNU software. Your call, though. I just want to encourage it as an option (*especially* as it's easier to contribute code when it's entirely your own work -- if people start making pull requests, it might complicate matters).

Comment: By the way, Emacs already comes with `cl-gensym` (from `cl-lib`).

Comment: @npostavs, I know this. Frankly, `mmt-gensym` has better documentation, documentation of `cl-gensym` does not describe certain features of the function. Such minor duplication is OK, `f` library duplicates a lot of Emacs built-ins for consistency.

Comment: You can use `defalias` and pass a new docstring. I agree that minor duplication is OK, but in this specific case it's better not to have 2 gensyms that each use a separate counter.

Comment: @npostavs, counter is only used to distinguish gensyms for readability (as well as string prefix) in result of `macroexpand-1` for example, because symbols are uninterned anyway, i.e. `(eq (gensym 5) (gensym 5)) => nil`. On the other hand your proposition is worth considering.

Comment: @npostavs, I think I will do that change, thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's precisely for readability that there should be only a single counter.

Answer (score 3):

In my personal libraries, I also prefer to maintain a connection with Common Lisp idioms and syntax as much as possible, to avoid context switching. Of course, if I would develop public libraries I would try to avoid it. Common Lisp perspective seems not favoured by main Emacs developers, although I know a few representative ones that do favour `cl-lib` parlance.

In any case, I use [el-get](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get) to manage the external packages. `el-get` allows to fecth directly from EmacsWiki. I have this in my `init.el`:

```
(el-get-bundle macro-utils)
```

Which nicely allows one to use `with-gensyms`, as you asked, and also `once-only`:

```
(defmacro double (x)
  (once-only (x)
    `(+ ,x ,x)))
```

Comment: +1, That's first normal answer out there. This is worth considering, although I don't really like idea of depending on Emacs wiki using `el-get`. I wouldn't mind using such a scheme in my init file, though. The thing is: in structured systems like (M)ELPA, there are explicit list of dependencies that those systems can analyse and manage installation of dependencies for you or show user dependencies of a package. I would like to follow the model.

Comment: @mark el-get take cares of dependencies too. See for example this recipe: https://github.com/dimitri/el-get/blob/master/recipes/org-sync.rcp I do use both, melpa and el-get, as they mix quite well. See the README at the link in the answer for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Your question appears to be only "Where can I find `with-gensyms`?" If so, it should probably be closed, and in any case you seem to now have the answer, from Google.

As to the Emacs-Lisp way of doing things, the answer is **`make-symbol`**.

And in fact, `org-with-gensyms`, which you mention, just uses `make-symbol`:

```el
(defmacro org-with-gensyms (symbols &rest body)
  `(let ,(mapcar (lambda (s)
                   `(,s (make-symbol (concat "--" (symbol-name ',s))))) symbols)
     ,@body))
```

Comment: Google didn't tell me name of reusable library that provides `when-gensyms`, thus I don't think this should be closed.

Comment: @Mark: `org-mode` comes with Emacs out of the box, so that's pretty reusable.

Comment: @Dan, This function is undocumented ad-hoc thing that developers of `org-mode` needed, and they coded it. It's not public API. Org is not a library for such macros by its nature. In principle if developers of `org-mode` decide to change something and remove this helper macro, what other people who depend on it should do? Should they say "Sorry our package doesn't work anymore because org-developers changed an internal ad-hoc macro that they needed"? I don't know how you @Drew, and @Dan can propose such ideas seriously. I regret asking the question because I see no understanding here.

Comment: +1 for `make-symbol` -- this is good tool to mention, but I don't think your post answers the question. You should understand that I knew how to implement this thing long before I asked my question, like any programmer knows how to program sort function, but never does it manually. You judge from position of user who needs to hack his/her init file, not from position of developer who needs collection of standard abstractions given without need to reimplement them again and again. If I don't get what I want, I will just write such a library myself on principle. And post its name as an answer.

Comment: @Mark Why not do `report-emacs-bug` as phils suggested in a comment on your question?

Comment: @kaushalmodi, even if I do and they listen to me, this will take effect only in Emacs 25. What about older versions of Emacs that still will be used for quite some time, I think. This is a good think to do in long term, but it doesn't solve the problem in hand.

Comment: Mark: Sure it does. You previously argued that the org-mode maintainers might remove the macro. This way you would know that it was definitely available (in org-mode for a certain range of Emacs versions, and in its new location for subsequent versions), and therefore you know how to support all of those versions of Emacs. (If you want to support old versions of Emacs but you don't want to deal with any backward or forward compatibility issues with this macro, your only option is to include your own custom equivalent.)

Comment: @phils, let's make it clear, I should detect Emacs version, if it's lower than 25, I should use `org-with-gensyms`, otherwise I should use `with-gensyms` (standardized, extracted from org as per my hypothetical request), everything correct?

Comment: Yes; but you could approach that in different ways. I would suggest that if you detect an older version of Emacs you could simply `(defalias 'with-gensyms 'org-with-gensyms)` and then the rest of your code is unchanged. If you know that the new name is reserved for use in Emacs 25, and that the old and new macros are compatible, then this should be a perfectly safe approach. I expect you would `eval-when-compile` your version test and `require`ment of `org-macs`.